# Exploiting sudo_debug()

Tags: linux, bash, exploit

I've tried this assignment for a few weeks unsuccessfully, so i'm trying my luck here.

Please do bear with me if i ask n00b questions. I'm new to linux OS and exploit writing.
I am currently trying to exploit sudo_debug ([CVE: 2012-0809](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/alerts/sudo_debug.html)), using a pure format string exploit.

I have Sudo version 1.8.3p1 installed for this purpose. 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04. I've disable ASLR.

The solution has to be in the form of bash script.

```
fmt="%p"
echo $fmt
ln -s /bin/sudo $fmt
./$fmt -D9 -A ls
rm $fmt
```

Q1. I tried using gdb to run the script unsuccessfully. I was thinking of using gdb to look into the memory space to understand more about this vuln.

Q2. I can only use gdb on the sudo if i am superuser. Not sure whether it will be the same if i execute the script as a normal user.

Q3. I know the address of user_details.uid do i just overwrite this with 0x0? I understand that \x00 will terminate a string. So how can i write 0x0 using %n?

Q4. I've also attempted to use the disclosed exploit (https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/25134/). But it is not working with the script method.

Any suggestions on how i can proceed with this assignment is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start smaller. You won't be able to debug a suid app, but you don't need the suid bit to discover how things work. You don't need the variables first. You don't need askpass or a specific command, so drop those too. Try simply `ln -s /bin/sudo %p ; ./%p -D9` - does it crash? Work from there.

Comment: Hi viraptor, thanks for the direction. Yes, it crashes and i have managed spot where the buffer i'm writing to is. However, it seems to move with every character that i add. E.g if my input buffer is A*200, 0x41 appears at say %255$p. If i add one more "A", it might move to say %256$p. Why is this happening?

Comment: And also, when i attempt to use %n to write to a particular address, it appears that my string was parsed again. I was expecting to see 0x12345678 with a input of \x78\x56\x34\x12. However, i saw the hex of my input, e.g. 0x3231785c. Am i not doing it correctly? I tested with some trial codes using scut's paper and it runs perfectly fine. Am i suppose to do something else in bash script? using (printf)?

Comment: Another very important skillset that i've yet to fully pick up to further this track was to read and understand the codes. The answer lies in understanding the operation of the binary. Cheers~!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **value returned** by the `getprogname()`, which should be a stack address that stores the format string controlled by you. Then use the `vfprintf()` overflow the **uid**.

Comment: I'm a beginner also working at this problem and I'm not sure how to use the stack address to overflow yet. I only know that I can write with %n to the stack address but not sure how to jump to the uid location